# Why piecewise functions have open curly braces and no closing bracket?

Tags: functions, continuity, notation

For example, the mod function

$$|x|=\begin{cases}-x,&{\text{if }}x<0,\\+x,&{\text{if }}x\geq 0.\end{cases}$$

Why is a closing bracket not there? And who started this notation?

Also, please provide some kind of logic and evidence.

Thank you for your effort and time!

Comment: That's how it's usually written. Is there something unclear with this notation?

Comment: It is only a notation, in order to group the (several) cases of the definition.

Comment: I strongly object closing this question. It is quite elementary, but clear and important for maths newcomers.

Comment: Since this is usually at the end of a line, people found it unnecessary to add a closing brace. Also, just because it looks like the brace that you're used to from brace pairs, doesn't mean it is one, functionally. See the braces you can put under equations to give names to parts

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Not unclear but braces are in pairs, this feels unusual

Comment: I can assure you that it's totally usual in this context.

Comment: @lisyarus On second thought, I think you are right. I retracted.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut But who started this notation?

Comment: That's a very good question.

Comment: Indeed, I do not know the story of this notation? Perhaps you can add this sentence in your question.

Comment: Ok, if you all think this question is not worth it, I can delete it.

Comment: The usual terminology is "absolute value function"

Comment: It is not a functional brace. It is just a symbol indicating that we seperate at least two cases.

Comment: Best is probably to close this question because basically everything has been said to avoid unnecessary answers that will soon or latere occur, but to keep the question visible for other readers. The risk is then that it is reopened , but we must die one death.

Comment: @Peter Well, not everything has been said. The OP asked in the comments (and now in the question): where does it come from? The answer does not seem obvious. I don't know, and I know of no good source that would likely give the answer.

Comment: I think this question should be migrated to the "History of Science and Mathematics" StackExchange site.

Comment: I wonder if this notation is older than the similar use for the grand staff in classical music notation.

Comment: @ZhenLin It's entirely possible (and I believe, very likely) that its use in mathematics comes from something similar in another field. If only because the introduction of piecewise functions is rather recent: if I remember correctly, mathematicians of the 18th century were reluctant to consider a function that is not given by a single formula (that can be an infinite series, for instance). Then many discoveries in mathematics have made piecewise functions necessary.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it will find a better home and better answers on http://hsm.stackexchange.com